# c# on mac OSX 10.15.6 UpdateLayer() stroke line not display in NScustomview

Tags: c#, macos, line, nsview, custom-view

I am new on MAC programming specific to OSX in C#;
I would like to be able to refresh a customview to draw dynamically lines (i.e. stock charts)
using an array from ViewController.cs on a mousedown action, I am not quite there at all.

First, I am trying to figure out why nothing at all is display using UpdateLayer() method
while I am trying to stroke a line. If I would use the same stroke line in drawrect it kind of word only once and I cannot pass any parameter from ViewController.cs,
I am also trying to figure out how to refresh the customview, so the drawrect is only called once. I though I need to use UpdateLayer() instead if I want to refresh the view, but nothing is display from UpdateLayer, the line stroke is not working.

I have been searching a long time on the web for clear example in C# cocoa,
most of example I could find are in other languages such Swift, which they use setneedsdisplay on a mouse click to refresh a customview, I was not able to find an equivalent in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Foundation;
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace Mac13_UpdLayer
{
    public partial class CustView : AppKit.NSView
    {
        #region Constructors

        // Called when created from unmanaged code
        public CustView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        // Called when created directly from a XIB file
        [Export("initWithCoder:")]
        public CustView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
        {
            Initialize();

        }

        // Shared initialization code
        void Initialize()
        {
            this.WantsLayer = true;
            this.LayerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy.OnSetNeedsDisplay;

        }

        public override void DrawRect(CGRect dirtyRect)
        {

               base.DrawRect(dirtyRect);

        }

        public override bool WantsUpdateLayer
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        public override void UpdateLayer()
        {


            base.UpdateLayer();
            NSColor.LabelColor.Set();
            NSColor.Magenta.Set();
            NSBezierPath path = new NSBezierPath();
            path.LineWidth = 3;
            CGPoint c001 = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            CGPoint c003 = new CGPoint(this.AccessibilityFrame.Width, this.AccessibilityFrame.Height);
            path.MoveTo(c001);
            path.LineTo(c003);
            path.Stroke();


        }
        #endregion
    }
}

using System;

using AppKit;
using Foundation;

namespace Mac13_UpdLayer
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


       

            //   this.View.Layer.BackgroundColor = NSColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
   
            }
        }

        partial void ButRefAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {
            //declare array
            //refresh customview from array
        }
    }
}
```